# Is there a way to send the response that's returned from dialogflow (fulfillment) to another account

Tags: dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using slack with dialogflow fulfillment to create a chat bot.
Can userA send a message to dialogflow and dialogflow return a response to userB?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, the WebHook responses goes in the conversation which originates the call.

You can create a custom logic (in your Webhook) to initiate a message to another user. This depends on the Channel, for example with the Telegram API you can notify a user having his/her chat ID.